# Azure devops stakeholder access

Tags: azure-devops

I have a setup on Devops where I want to give and external account (not part of the company) access to the repos. I thought that the Stakeholders would have at least read only access there but seems not.

I've invited a new user (external) with Access Level = Stakeholder, given access to the project X and made him a member of Project Contributors for the project.

So the question is, should Stakeholders here have access to the repos? is there a way for me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using private repos for your project then stakeholders only have access to the following features:

1. Dashboards, Wiki, Boards, Project and Organization settings - Partial access
2. Repos, Test Plans - No access
3. Pipelines, Notifications, Semantic Search - Full access

If you are using public repos for your project then stakeholders only have access to the following features:

1. Dashboards, Wiki, Boards, Repos, Pipelines, Notifications, Semantic Search - Full access
2. Test Plans - No access
3. Project and Organization settings - Partial access

If you want details on Stakeholder access rights for each of the features, [go here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azdevops&tabs=stakeholder)

I hope that helps.

Comment: stakeholder wants to play the role in repos? if yes how you want to configure or enabling repos to them

Comment: My goal here is to give clients read only access to the repos in case they want / need. Since stakeholders already had access to boards and a few other pieces it felt natural to me to think they would have at least partial access to the repos