# How to setup Azure DevOps Repo Read Only Access

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

**Objective:** Allow different clients access to only read/pull from my private repo.

**Overview:**
Listed are the different options that I am aware of:

- I could invite the clients and give them access to the `Basic` access level but do know what to have to pay for different users just to read/clone from the repo.
- I could create a single user with `Basic` access level and then create git access tokens for them individually. However, I did not see a way to restrict the access tokens to be project/repo specific. Instead, the access tokens create had the same privileges as the created user.

**Question:** What is the best practice to provide access to an external user to only access the private Azure DevOps repo?

*Note:* I have seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54455373/azure-devops-stakeholder-access) and did not know if there were other options.

Comment: Since it's private repo, you need to add the user into current organization so that he can access the repo. Then you can follow my answer to limit the permission of the user.

Comment: Hi metthew, is there any update for this issue? Just checking in to see if my answer makes some help, feel free to let me know if your issue persists !

Answer (score 7):

> To make the user only have read access to all repos in one project:

You may consider making the user a `reader` instead of `contributor` or `Project Administrators`, so the user can have only read access to the repos in one project.

`Organization Settings=>Users(General)=>Manage user=> select Project reader`.

[image]

More details about `project readers` you can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions-access?view=azure-devops#azure-repos).

> To make the user only have read access to one special repos in one project:

We can control related permissions from `Project Settings=>Repositories(Repos)=>Version Control Administrators`:

[image]

Hope all above helps :)

Comment: Bummer, none of this helped unfortunately. What does "add user to current organization" mean? There is no "select Project Readers" in that path. Azure Devops is a colossal mess that is overly difficult to manage. What I would expect from engineers being asked to design something without any designers.